# Creating a helper in a ruby model for quick access

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Video model that contains a number of different encoded versions of the video. Each encoded version has the same fields. The schema looks something like this:

```
Videos:
 id: integer
 url: string
 version_mp4_id: integer
 version_mp4_encoding_status: string
 version_mp4_dimensions: string
 version_ogg_id: integer
 version_ogg_encoding_status: string
 version_ogg_dimensions: string
```

Now, it's easy enough to just say **v.version_mp4_id = 1**, but I was trying to make it a bit smarter, so that I could treat them as if they were each their own entity while still keeping all the information in the same table.

So, I wrote a class called **VideoVersion** that is a nested class of **Video**. It looks like this:

```
class VideoVersion
  attr_accessor :id, :url, :encoding_status, :dimensions

  def initialize(video, format)
    @video = video
    @format = format
    @id = @video.read_attribute("version_#{format}_id")
    @url = @video.read_attribute("version_#{format}_url")
    @dimensions = @video.read_attribute("version_#{format}_dimensions")
    @encoding_status = @video.read_attribute("version_#{format}_encoding_status")
  end

  def attributes
    return {
      "version_#{@format}_id" =>  @id,
      "version_#{@format}_url" =>  @url,
      "version_#{@format}_dimensions" =>  @dimensions,
      "version_#{@format}_encoding_status" =>  @encoding_status
    }
  end
  alias :attrs :attributes

  def save!
    @video.update_attributes(attributes)      
  end

end
```

and I have three methods on the video class like this:

```
def version(format)
  raise UnsupportedFormat unless FORMATS.include?(format)
  return VideoVersion.new(self, format)
end

def mp4
  version('mp4')
end

def ogg
  version('ogg')
end
```

This allows me to say **v.mp4.id** and have it return the right information. That's all fine and dandy.

The problems show up when trying to change values the same way, or when changes are made directly to the video object and then accessed via the v.mp4 shortcut. For example:

```
v = Video.find(1)
vv = VideoVersion.new(v, 'mp4')
puts vv.encoding_status
=> 'started'
v.version_mp4_encoding_status = 'finished'
puts vv.encoding_status
=> 'started'
v.mp4.encoding_status = 'pending'
puts v.version_mp4_encoding_status
=> 'finished'
```

Because the video is passed by value, the original object doesn't get affected. This is pretty obvious.

Long story short, I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way to accomplish the shortcut without all the extra hassle and issues. Method missing? Something else? Or, am I just being lazy and overcomplicating my code... :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy, am not sure I fully understand a couple of your methods, however it appears to me that you could roll all of the functionality of your VideoVersion class into your Videos class. I'm going on the assumption that your issue is more the 'nested' class problem.